# Python decorator my function check

Tags: python, python-decorators

In my class i wrote this method:

```
def ts_prep(self, test_id):
    ltouple = ()
    tab_lib = temp_library.objects.filter(main_id=test_id)
    l1 = ["Settings", ""]
    ltouple += (l1,)
    if tab_lib.count() == 0: ltouple = (l1, ["", ""])
    l = []
    for r in tab_lib.iterator():
        l.append(str(r.l_type))
        l.append(str(r.l_val))
        ltouple += (l,)
        l = []

    tslist = [x for x in ltouple]
    return tslist
```

How could i create a decorator for my method that perform the if tab_lib check for add it at all the method that make the same check?

i try

```
def p_decorate(func):
    def func_wrapper(test_id):
       tab_lib = temp_library.objects.filter(main_id=test_id)
        l1 = ["Settings", ""]
        ltouple += (l1,)
        if tab_lib.count() == 0: ltouple = (l1, ["", ""])
        return ltouple
   return func_wrapper
```

but it does not seem to work

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the function doing and what have you tried so far? SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your code can be simplified a lot in general. This should be equivalent:

```
def ts_prep(self, test_id):
    tab_lib = temp_library.objects.filter(main_id=test_id)
    tslist = [["Settings", ""]]
    if tab_lib.count() == 0:
        tslist.append(["", ""])
    for r in tab_lib.iterator():
        tslist.append([str(r.l_type), str(r.l_val)])

    return tslist
```

To answer your question, you could then do this:

```
import functools

def decorator(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(test_id):
        tab_lib = temp_library.objects.filter(main_id=test_id)
        tslist = [["Settings", ""]]
        if tab_lib.count() == 0:
            tslist.append(["", ""])
        return func(tab_lib, tslist)

    return wrapper

@decorator
def ts_prep(self, tab_lib, tslist):
    for r in tab_lib.iterator():
        tslist.append([str(r.l_type), str(r.l_val)])

    return tslist
```

Comment: AttributeError: PrepareRst instance has no attribute '__trunc__'

Comment: @ManuelSanti which code raises that error and at what line and do you not get the same error with your own code?

Comment: Thanks a lot, now is ok!